# How to automatize Word from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In a Windows server 2012 r2 64 bit I have an old .NET application rewritten in VB that runs under IIS 8. In this application there is a piece of code that open/write a Word document.

My requirement is to automatize Word to use in this .NET application.

1. Is still possible to automatize Word to use it in a .NET application?
2. If yes, what are the correct steps to automatize Word to use it in a .NET application without use Visual Studio?

Thanks at all.

**Update**

Hi.

Thanks for your response.

For "automatize Word" I mean the fact to invoke Word (through Interop or the CreateObject function) from this .NET application.

To accomplish this requirement, first I have installed Word on this server. After, I have also installed the Interop to communicate with Word but probably something is not working correct because after the installation I haven't see nothing about the Interop in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\ (if the Interop is installed here). For now, I have see only a reference in C:\Windows\assembly.

Then, after days of useless researchs I don't know anymore what I am missing or what I can do in order to see this .NET application working correctly.

Somebody know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's still possible, but for both then and now it's a really really really really really really really bad idea on a server. The problem is, to this day, MS refuses to provide better first-party options, and third party stuff is flaky and stupid expensive.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions out there. [*ms word edit c# vb.net*](https://www.google.com/search?q=ms+word+edit+c%23+vb.net+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: Define "automatize Word". What _exactly_ do you need to do?

Answer (score -2):

From [VB.NET Word Interop Example](https://www.dotnetperls.com/word-vbnet):

> Please add the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly to your project.
> Go to Project -> Add Reference.
>
> ```
> Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
>
> Module Module1
>     Sub Main()
>         ' Create application instance.
>         Dim app As Application = New Application
>
>         ' Open specified file.
>         Dim doc As Document = app.Documents.Open("C:\word.doc")
>
>         ' Loop through all words.
>         Dim count As Integer = doc.Words.Count
>         For i As Integer = 1 To count
>             ' Write word to screen.
>             Dim text As String = doc.Words(i).Text
>             Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", i, text)
>         Next
>
>         ' Quit the application.
>         app.Quit()
>     End Sub
> End Module
> ```